# Angular 2 How to create role for Admin side and Client side?

Tags: angular

I want to create Admin role and user role for separate routes

**app.routing.ts**

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    loadChildren: './client/client.route.module#ClientRouteModule'
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.route.module#AdminRouteModule'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

in this code how to create and add role for user and admin. something else add in child routes?
I want to create role for / for open frontend login and /admin for admin login still i have a problem for login without role. once login in frontend then admin automatic logged in because role is not added in local storage. I want to define role and store in local storage

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Admin navigation/routes separate from Client side navigation/routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619421/angular-2-admin-navigation-routes-separate-from-client-side-navigation-routes)

Comment: no i want to create role for / for open frontend login and /admin for admin login still i have a problem for login without role. once login in frontend then admin automatic logged in because role is not added in local storage. I want to define role and store in local storge